# Should I reorganize my tests when I extracted code to dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm practicing with TDD and I've done the simplest possible implementation that satisfies my test. Now after second and third test I see that I could extract piece of my logic into dependency. What should I do with existing tests? SHould I leave them as they are and test this dependency indirectly? Or should I "rewrite" my tests and split them into pieces using stubs/mocks in original cases?

Comment: The [one book](http://www.amazon.com/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Code/dp/0131495054?tag=duckduckgo-canonical-20) for this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, I'd leave your original tests, since they're operating as a *regression* test. i.e. do the tests still work now you've reworked the original code.

You can then write additional tests around the extracted functionality. It would possibly make sense to write more complex tests at this point to test the extracted functionality directly rather than throught the integration layer that you've identified/refactored out.

Comment: So I will have part of extracted class exercised indirectly and another part tested directly as I write those more complex tests, right? Or should I repeat those tests again in this newly created test class?

Comment: I would perhaps concentrate the tests on the extracted component and perhaps just write a few around its integration into the larger component. The complexity of this integration would drive your balance of tests

Comment: The key here is "balance". The existing tests act as a regression and also as an example how to use the subject with actual dependencies. However, if you find the existing tests spell out the implementation details of the dependencies there's a danger of the tests becoming too brittle -- remove as much duplication as possible or look to stubs to alleviate this concern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a silver bullet answer there. Solely based on what you describe I would  be inclined to:

1. Leave the existing tests as they are now
2. Add new tests specifically for the extracted dependencies

If you'd end up exactly duplicating the test code, you might want to mitigate, but it's important to keep testing that the "wholly integrated feature" works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In `refactor` phase of `Test Driven Development`, it could be refactoring of either business code or corresponding test. So while you are refactoring the code, you should take measures to refactor the test cases too to make them pass.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Answer (score 0):

Extracting to a dependency is probably refactoring, since the overall behavior remains the same, you only spread it over more classes. Refactoring is the third and last step in the TDD cycle and happens just after your test is green, without adding a new test. So here's what I'd do :

- Start from a state where all your tests are green.
- Extract behavior B from Class1 to Class2.
- Check for broken tests. If there aren't any, then either you forgot to test B or your refactoring tool has superpowers.
- Correct the unit test that tests behavior B so that it operates on Class2 instead of Class1.
- (optional) Create collaboration tests verifying that Class1 talks to Class2 correctly and vice versa. You may want to use mocks and/or stubs for that.

Comment: I don't really get this third bullet here. If I extract behavior using automatic refactoring I just change internals so my tests should still pass, am I right? After such extraction my tests become such "collaboration tests" as they test interaction with Class1 and Class2. Should I still write tests for behavior B if it is still tests indirectly?

Comment: As I see it, moving B from Class1 to Class2 probably means asserting on variables that can no longer be found in Class1 but in Class2. Your test will probably break, or, in the "best case", the automatic refactoring will modify the getters of these variables in Class1 so that they point to getters in class2, which keeps the test green but is ugly. Also, the refactoring tool won't rename your unit test to reflect that Class2 now holds the behavior, which is crucial for the readability of your test...

Comment: ...By "collaboration test" I mean a *unit test* that verifies if the class under test talks to its dependencies properly. A *unit test*'s validity depends on the correctness of only one unit of code (only Class1 in our case) so you can't exercise the test against a real implementation of your dependency, you have to stub or mock out the dependency (Class2). See http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Stub.html and http://xunitpatterns.com/Mock%20Object.html